# JSF 2 modal panel

Tags: jquery, css, jsf-2

How can i make a modal panel in JSF 2?
I tried using javascript as in: 
http://www.pat-burt.com/web-development/how-to-do-a-css-popup-without-opening-a-new-window/

and a jquery plugin called SimpleModal.

but the modal panel at best appears for a split of a second and then disappears.
So how can i achieve a modal panel in pure JSF 2 (no richfaces or such)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you open to adopting JSF 2 component libraries? PrimeFaces for example has a `<p:dialog>` for exactly this purpose. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you calling your modal panel? If you are using a `commandButton` / `commandLink` with the `onclick` event, then you will have to finish your call by `return false;`, like that:

```
<h:commandButton onclick="popup('...'); return false;" ...>
```

If you do not set this, then the popup will appear, and then a request is sent to the server. The page will finally be refreshed, which will close this popup.